# Where can I find the viewing properties on ERDAS?

Tags: vector, erdas-imagine

The instructions state to click on vector and then viewing properties yet I cannot find the viewing properties.

[image]

When I click on vector in the main menu there is no option for viewing properties. [image]

Comment: I don't understand the useless negative mark within my post. How much research can you put into looking for the viewing properties when you're just learning the program. This information is not readily available online, I always look before posting here, and if it is please send me the link as I was not able to find it. I'm here to learn how to use the system, this question is useful for any beginner.

Comment: Not sure if this will help. But you haven't loaded a vector layer into the view yet. That may have implications in the options presented to you.

Comment: The GIS lab at the school I work for was having similar issues. See if you can find out what version of IMAGINE that guide was written for, and whether it matches up with the version you're running.

Comment: I think we might go to the same school... FAU? Yea the instructions we are given are from an older version of ERDAS, and as someone who's just learning it for the first time it makes it difficult. @JoshC

Answer (score 1):

**Viewing Properties** are found in the dynamic Vector tab group, as opposed to the static Vector tab in your screenshot.

This dynamic tab group appears when a vector layer is loaded into the viewer and is selected. Then look under the Style tab for this particular item.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I realized that I was not even focusing on the correct viewer. @joshC